# How to read from text file and load it into memory using a struct?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, c99, ansi-c

I have a text file like these:

```
Naruto, Wind, 85, 48, 35, 63
Neji, Fire, 57, 53, 81, 45
Gaara, Earth, 73, 47, 96, 50
Sasuke, Fire, 68, 82, 72, 41
Kankurou, Water, 59, 42, 97, 60
```

and i have my struct

```
typedef struct ninja{ 
    char* name; 
    char* element; 
    int ninjutsu ; 
    int genjutsu ; 
    int taijutsu ; 
    int defesa ; 
} Ninja ;
```

I need to read the text file and load it directly into memory using this struct. Should I create some arrays, store the info inside char by char, and then convert the types (when int) and then load it?.

```
void file(){
    FILE *file = fopen("ninjas.txt", "r");
    int c;
    if (file) {

       while ((c = getc(file)) != ','){
          putchar(c);
       }
       while ((c = getc(file)) != ','){
          putchar(c);
       }
       while ((c = getc(file)) != ','){
          putchar(c);
       }
       while ((c = getc(file)) != ','){
          putchar(c);
       }
       while ((c = getc(file)) != ','){
          putchar(c);
       }
       while ((c = getc(file)) != '\n'){
          putchar(c);
       }

   fclose(file);
}
```

}

Comment: Please show what you have such that we can give advice.

Comment: JUST AN OBSERVATION: Each line is a ninja, and each ninja will be an element of a linked list, but that part I understand well. I just need to read it right.

Comment: Im just trying to understand how to read each info properly, not to load it into mem, which i already know how to do.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by _" I always end up some of the line information wrong"_

Comment: You can make use of these three functions: `fopen`, [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), and [`strok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: Please answer the following:
1. Can you make any assumptions about maximum length of a line or maximum length of names and elements?
2. Do you need to error check the input or is this an exercise and you are allowed to assume the file is correct?
3. Are you allowed to use any extra memory bigger than a single char?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No need to check error, the file is correct . 3) yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be in parsing of input after reading from file. I write a solution which run perfectly in my system (Ubantu using gcc).
I used fgets() method for read a line then parse it using strtok() function.

Here is code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_RECORD 100

    #define MAX_LINE 200
    typedef struct ninja{ 
        char* name; 
        char* element; 
        int ninjutsu ; 
        int genjutsu ; 
        int taijutsu ; 
        int defesa ; 
    } Ninja ;

        int main(int argc,char** argv){

                FILE *fptr=fopen("input.txt","r");
                if(fptr==NULL){
                printf("Error in openning file\n");
                return 1;
                }
                Ninja ninjas[MAX_RECORD];
                int total_record=0;
                char line_buffer[MAX_LINE];
                while(total_record< MAX_RECORD && fgets(line_buffer,MAX_LINE,fptr)!=NULL)
                {
                        char *curr_record=NULL;
                        curr_record=strtok(line_buffer,",");
                        ninjas[total_record].name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
                        strcpy(ninjas[total_record].name,curr_record);
                        curr_record=strtok(NULL,",");
                        ninjas[total_record].element=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
                        strcpy(ninjas[total_record].element,curr_record);
                        curr_record=strtok(NULL,",");
                        ninjas[total_record].ninjutsu=atoi(curr_record);
                        curr_record=strtok(NULL,",");
                        ninjas[total_record].genjutsu=atoi(curr_record);
                        curr_record=strtok(NULL,",");
                        ninjas[total_record].taijutsu=atoi(curr_record);
                        curr_record=strtok(NULL,",");
                        ninjas[total_record].defesa=atoi(curr_record);
                        total_record++;
                }
                for(int i=0;i<total_record;i++)
                {
                        printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d",ninjas[i].name,ninjas[i].element,ninjas[i].ninjutsu,ninjas[i].genjutsu,ninjas[i].taijutsu,ni$
                        printf("\n");
                }
                fclose(fptr);
                return 0;
        }
```

Output:

```
Naruto  Wind 85 48 35 63
Neji  Fire 57 53 81 45
Gaara  Earth 73 47 96 50
Sasuke  Fire 68 82 72 41
Kankurou  Water 59 42 97 60
```

Comment: Wow! That is just perfect! I was approaching something like your code, but a lot messier and redundant haha, thanks very much!

Comment: @Susheel Dwivedi Why not using sscanf ?

Comment: Actually sscanf() takes space separated input and your file is   contains space after seperater(","). if you use sscanf() then , also comes as input and make you trouble when parsing integers using %d or something else. so its a safe way to parsing your file :).

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it! You guys think it is ok?

```
void file(){
    FILE *file = fopen("ninjas.txt", "r");
    char str[60];
    const char s[3] = ", ";
    char *token;
    if (file) {
        while (fgets (str, 60, file) != NULL){
           token = strtok(str, s);
           printf( " %s\n", token );
           token = strtok(NULL, s);
           printf( " %s\n", token );
           token = strtok(NULL, s);
           printf( " %s\n", token );
           token = strtok(NULL, s);
           printf( " %s\n", token );
          token = strtok(NULL, s);
          printf( " %s\n", token );
          token = strtok(NULL, s);
          printf( " %s\n", token );
      }
  fclose(file);
  }
```

}